# (click) event is not working only on IOS devices - angular 10 app

Tags: ios, angular, click

I noticed that my buttons are not working on the IOS devices, it seems that the click event is not called. Everything is working perfectly on the windows, android, Linux. Since I don't have access to any mac I was trying to debug it on the browserStack, I am getting this error every time I am trying to click the button:

`ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.path[4]')`

I might be completely wrong, but I think that it might be related with the SVG's rect that is inside of the button (I am using it as a progress bar), on the rect load event I am accessing it to find its length. Maby it is called "too early" so it cannot access the rect correctly. Previously I was using the `ngAfterViewInit` with the `setTimeout` inside to manage the same effect.

```html
  <rect
    #rect
    width="96"
    height="96"
    rx="8"
    fill="none"
    stroke-width="4"
    [ngStyle]="{
      'stroke-dasharray': strokeDasharray,
      'stroke-dashoffset': strokeDashoffset
    }"
    (load)="getRectLength()"
  />
```

```js
  getRectLength() {
    this.length = this.rect.nativeElement.getTotalLength();
    this.strokeDasharray = this.length;
  }
```

**Code:** 
https://github.com/mateuszkornecki/chess-clock/tree/master/src

**Live demo:**
https://mateuszkornecki.github.io/chess-clock/settings

**Steps to reproduce:** 
Simply click on one of the big buttons with the counter, after a click it should start counting.

I tested it on several IOS devices, it was not working on everyone regardless of the IOS version. That's my first project made with Angular so there is a chance that I've made a simple mistake. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the source of the problem. I was trying to use the `event.path` array on the click event. It looks that it is not available on the Safari. I fixed the problem by using the `event.composedPath` instead of the `event.path`


**References:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath